# How do I allow numeric-only input with Cordova / PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova

I'm writing an app where I would like to enable the user to click a button to enter a number.  When they click the button, or a nearby text box, I would like them to type in the value with a numeric-only keyboard.  How can I achieve this?

I am mostly interested in iOS, but a generic solution would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

I have researched a couple of alternatives:

1) Provide a [keyboard hint](http://blog.pamelafox.org/2012/05/triggering-numeric-keyboards-with-html5.html) to the OS for a text box.  This works, but the keyboard popping up screws up the layout and doesn't work well with focusing.

2) Use [notification.prompt](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.prompt), which works neatly, but is an alphanumeric keyboard.  This would be ideal, IF it supported a numeric keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the input type to `type="tel"` to force a number-pad.

```
<input name="someNumericOnlyInput" type="tel">
```